# Flink stateful functions, async calls with the python SDK

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

I'm trying out the Stateful Functions 2.1 API with the Python SDK and I can't see a clear way on how to make async calls to external api's without blocking the application.

Is this possible or can somebody send me on the right path?

Comment: If you are using gunicorn with either https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#asyncio-workers or https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#async-workers then, that should be already enough. While a request is "blocked" another requests for different keys can proceed.

Comment: @Igal that seems like a good solution. If you want you can write it as an answer and I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of StateFun 2.2.0, you can use the AsyncRequestReplyHandler.

From the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-master/sdk/python.html#serving-asynchronous-functions):

> The Python SDK ships with an additional handler,
> AsyncRequestReplyHandler, that supports Python’s awaitable functions
> (coroutines). This handler can be used with asynchronous Python
> frameworks, for example aiohttp.

```
@functions.bind("example/hello")
async def hello(context, message):
   response = await compute_greeting(message)
   context.reply(response)

from aiohttp import web

handler = AsyncRequestReplyHandler(functions)

async def handle(request):
   req = await request.read()
   res = await handler(req)
   return web.Response(body=res, content_type="application/octet-stream")

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.post('/statefun', handle)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  web.run_app(app, port=5000)
```

You can see [here](https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun/blob/master/statefun-examples/statefun-async-python-example/greeter/greeter.py) a complete example.